# Toilet Trained Cat... Almost

Tags: cats, training, toilet-training

So my wife and I set ourselves to training our cat to use the toilet. Over the course of several months, we performed the following steps and were met with great success.

1. We moved the covered litter box close to the toilet.
2. We switched the litter out for a soluble brand so it wouldn't wreck our plumbing.
3. We raised the litter box to the level of the toilet.
4. We removed the top of the covered litter box.
5. We moved it on top of the toilet.
6. My wife then molded an aluminum turkey pan to fit inside the bowl of the toilet and filled it with the soluble litter.
7. We cut a small hole in the center of the turkey pan.
8. Over time, we gradually expanded the size of the hole until there was nothing left for our kitty to stand on but the toilet seat.

Now, all that exists is the shining rim of the turkey pan below the toilet seat.

Our cat has been successfully peeing and pooping in the toilet for about 3 months or so now. That is until this last Christmas. When we put our tree up, it created a nice, little, isolated corner in our apartment. One day I discovered a poop in the corner. Since then, there have been a handful of incidents where she'll poop in the same corner if it's not covered with stuff, or like this morning, she'll poop right in ***front*** of the toilet on the mat. It doesn't happen every time, or even half the time, but just every now and then.

I have a hunch that our cat doesn't particularly like the sensation of pooping on the toilet because it splashes up onto her butt. Things that I've read say that if a cat doesn't like their pooping space, they'll pick a different spot. I *know* there are people who have had complete success with toilet training.

At this point, we're determined to have her using the toilet, so going back to a litter box isn't really an option. Has anyone else had this same problem? And how would you recommend addressing it?

---

**Edit**

I have considered using toilet paper to cover the surface of the water. This has proven... from experience... to reduce/eliminate splash entirely, but I don't think it will stay there all day, and I don't think I could train her to put toilet paper over the surface of the water.

This really comes down to whether or not this is just something behavioral that needs extra training/addressing in some other manner, or if there's something creative that can be done to improve her experience.

Comment: Wow! I am really impressed with your determination and ability to have a cat use your own toilet.. thats some Meet the Parents stuff right there!!!

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog thank you. Honestly, it was pretty easy, it just took some patience. But we were assuming once she started using the toilet without anything in it, we'd be done. Didn't anticipate reaching this breaking point where she would just NOT use it sometimes. But it's all part of the adventure. lol.

Answer (score 7):

Breaking litterbox protocol can be an indication that the cat is ill. Assuming you've checked that...

(1) Treat all the places she's hit with an enzyme cleaner to neutralize the smell and not encourage reuse.

(2) Go back at least to the solid pan, show her it's solid again, ad resume the process from there.

Remember that you're asking the cat to do something that directly conflicts with its instincts. Not every cat will be able to cooperate.

(My solution is clumping litter and a non-automated self-cleaning litter tray. My kids "grew up" with it and are used to it, and it really isn't more than a minute or two of work per day go dump it into a covered pail and toss some replacement litter in. Full cleaning once a month. Painless enough for me.)